# SQL Query - How to suppress repeating values in the result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to suppress the repeating values in TotalCarton column. Have tried to replace the value either blank or null but went failed. Any help?

Here is the SQL Script:

```
SELECT ORDERS.StorerKey,
    ORDERS.OrderKey, 
    PackKey = (SELECT MAX(PackKey) FROM BAX_PACK_DTL WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ORderKey = ORDERS.OrderKey),
    PackHU = BAX_PACK_DTL.OuterPackID,
    SalesOrderNum = ( SELECT Upper(Max(ORDERDETAIL.CustShipInst01)) FROM ORDERDETAIL WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE OrderKey = ORDERS.OrderKey),
    DeliveryNum = Upper(ORDERS.ExternOrderKey),     
    TotalCarton = ( CASE BAX_PACK_DTL.PackType WHEN 'C' THEN Count(DISTINCT(BAX_PACK_DTL.OuterPackID))
                    ELSE 0 END ),
    TotalPallet = ( CASE BAX_PACK_DTL.PackType WHEN 'P' THEN Count(DISTINCT(BAX_PACK_DTL.OuterPackID))
                    ELSE 0 END ),
    SumCarton = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(OuterPackSeq)) FROM BAX_PACK_DTL WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE PackType = 'C' AND PackKey = '0000000211'),
    SumPallet = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(OuterPackSeq)) FROM BAX_PACK_DTL WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE PackType = 'P' AND PackKey = '0000000211'),             
    AddWho = Upper(ORDERS.EditWho), 
    ORDERS.AddDate
FROM ORDERS WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN ORDERDETAIL WITH (NOLOCK) ON ORDERS.StorerKey = ORDERDETAIL.StorerKey 
                AND ORDERS.OrderKey = ORDERDETAIL.OrderKey
            INNER JOIN PICKDETAIL WITH (NOLOCK) ON ORDERDETAIL.StorerKey = PICKDETAIL.StorerKey 
                AND ORDERDETAIL.OrderKey = PICKDETAIL.OrderKey
                AND ORDERDETAIL.OrderLineNumber = PICKDETAIL.OrderLineNumber
            INNER JOIN BAX_PACK_DTL WITH (NOLOCK) ON PICKDETAIL.OrderKey = BAX_PACK_DTL.OrderKey 
                AND PICKDETAIL.PickDetailKey = BAX_PACK_DTL.PickDetailKey
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ORDERKEY)) FROM PICKDETAIL WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE OrderKey = ORDERS.OrderKey ) > 0
AND BAX_PACK_DTL.PackKey = '0000000211'
AND BAX_PACK_DTL.OuterPackID IN 
('P111111111',
'P22222222',
'P33333333')
GROUP BY ORDERS.StorerKey,
    ORDERS.OrderKey, 
    ORDERS.ExternOrderKey,
    ORDERS.HAWB,
    ORDERS.SO,
    ORDERS.EditWho, 
    ORDERS.AddDate,
    PICKDETAIL.WaveKey,
    BAX_PACK_DTL.OuterPackID,
    BAX_PACK_DTL.PackKey,
    BAX_PACK_DTL.PackType
ORDER BY BAX_PACK_DTL.OuterPackID ASC
```

Below is the current result set based on the query above.
[image]

Comment: The `DeliveryNum` values are not the same for those two "duplicate" records.  _Which_ one do you want to retain, and why?

Comment: From OrderKey column until DeliveryNum is retained. Only the Total Carton should be suppress.

Comment: No, I'm saying that you have two duplicate rows, but what is the logic by which you retain/discard one of those rows?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks really strange. I would expect the query to use conditional aggregation and look more like this:

```
SELECT ORDERS.StorerKey, ORDERS.OrderKey, 
       PackKey = (SELECT MAX(PackKey) FROM BAX_PACK_DTL WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ORderKey = ORDERS.OrderKey),
       PackHU = BAX_PACK_DTL.OuterPackID,
       SalesOrderNum = ( SELECT Upper(Max(ORDERDETAIL.CustShipInst01)) FROM ORDERDETAIL WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE OrderKey = ORDERS.OrderKey),
       DeliveryNum = Upper(ORDERS.ExternOrderKey),     
       TotalCarton = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE BAX_PACK_DTL.PackType WHEN 'C' THEN BAX_PACK_DTL.OuterPackID END),
       TotalPallet = COUNT(DISTINCT CASE BAX_PACK_DTL.PackType WHEN 'P' THEN BAX_PACK_DTL.OuterPackID END),
       SumCarton = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(OuterPackSeq)) FROM BAX_PACK_DTL bpd WHERE pbd.PackType = 'C' AND pbd.PackKey = '0000000211'),
       SumPallet = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(OuterPackSeq)) FROM BAX_PACK_DTL bpd WHERE pbd.PackType = 'P' AND pbd.PackKey = '0000000211'),             
       AddWho = Upper(ORDERS.EditWho), 
       ORDERS.AddDate
FROM . . .
GROUP BY ORDERS.StorerKey, ORDERS.OrderKey, Upper(ORDERS.ExternOrderKey),
         Upper(ORDERS.EditWho), ORDERS.AddDate;
```

This may not be exact.  You have not qualified column names, given the table structure, and are using very arcane query syntax, mixing subqueries and aggregations.  But it should give an idea.